# How to retrieve large values from SQL Server columns using DB Library for C?

Tags: c, sql-server, freetds

I am using FreeTDS to process simple `SELECT` statements.

My problem is that I cannot get more than the first 4096 bytes of a large column value.

Let's say we have a table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tab (
   largecol varbinary(max),
   othercol int PRIMARY KEY
);
```

My code looks like this (simplified and omitting error checks):

```c
#include <sybfront.h>
#include <sybdb.h>

int main ()
{
    DBPROCESS *dbproc;
    LOGINREC *login;
    char *data;
    DBINT len;

    /* setup */
    dbinit();
    login = dblogin();

    DBSETLUSER(login, "username");
    DBSETLPWD(login, "password");
    DBSETLAPP(login, "my_program");
    DBSETLPACKET(login, 10000);
    DBSETLNATLANG(login, "us_english");
    DBSETLCHARSET(login, "UTF-8");

    /* connect */
    dbproc = dbopen(login, "hostname");
    dbuse(dbproc, "dbname");

    /* execute query */
    dbcmd(dbproc, "SELECT largecol, othercol FROM tab");
    dbsqlexec(dbproc);
    dbresults(dbproc);

    /* retrieve result */
    dbnextrow(dbproc);
    data = (char *)dbdata(dbproc, 1);
    len = dbdatlen(dbproc, 1);

    /* more processing */
}
```

Now no matter how large the data in `largecol` are, I never get more than 4096 bytes in `data` and `len`.

The only lead I have to make this work is the [`dbreadtext`](https://documentation.help/dblibc/dbc_pdc07_3a7o.htm) function, but I don't understand how to use it. The only bit of information I get is:

> Use `dbreadtext` instead of `dbnextrow` to read `SQLTEXT` and `SQLIMAGE` values.

That function does not take a column number as argument, so I have no idea how to use it. Can it only be used with queries that retrieve only a single column?

How can I retrieve large column data?

Comment: Thanks, I was more (really) asking if it was `text`, but it's not, so killed that thought train. :)

Comment: @Larnu I also tried with `varchar(max)`, `text` and `image`, and the behavior is the same for all. Is there a problem with `text`?

Comment: Here is the explanation for `dbreadtext()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/readtext-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FreeTDS has an option, `text size`, which can be set in `freetds.conf`:

See table 3.3, `text size`:
https://www.freetds.org/userguide/freetdsconf.html

Give that a try?

Comment: Ah, this looks right. It also points me to [`SET TEXTSIZE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-textsize-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), which may be the simpler solution for me. I'll try it, then accept your answer.